# Without a calculator, find $\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Without a calculator, find $\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$.

I started AP Calc today. I’m a sophomore and I skipped precalc and, well, I am utterly confused.

Can someone please teach me how to solve this from the basics by hand? Thank you so much!

Comment: the answer is already there because the teacher gave it to us, btw. idk how to show my work :’(

Comment: It is usually a memorized value, along with the rest of [the unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#/media/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) for other info. [This](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ReviewIntro.aspx) is a good source for learning math online.

Comment: Often, the hardest part of learning Calculus is remembering what you learned in Precalculus (and Algebra, and Geometry). So, skipping Precalc puts you at a *significant* disadvantage. ... You should ask your instructor for the Precalculus textbook (and request access to the Teacher's Manual from time to time), then fill yourself in on the topics you missed. And/or, you can view a bunch of Khan Academy videos or whatever. Math.SE answers can be enlightening and thorough, but they're no substitute for proper lessons spanning an entire course.

Comment: thank you everyone for the helpful information and websites :)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Consider an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ and draw its height $\overline{AH}$ related to the side $\overline{BC}$, which is also the median. Thus the cosine is given by
\begin{align*}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{HC}{AC} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, the double-angle identity implies $$\cos(\pi/3)=\cos(2(\pi/6))=1-2\sin(\pi/6)^2.$$
But we also know (sine/cosine of complementary angles) that 
$$\cos(\pi/3)=\sin(\pi/2-\pi/3)=\sin(\pi/6).$$

Hence $\cos(\pi/3)=1-2\cos(\pi/3)^2.$ One solution to this is $\cos(\pi/3)=-1$, which is obviously not correct. That leaves the second solution, which is $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

The "end result" is 1/2, and this is my "quick route"

We have π radian = 180 degree, so π/3 radian = 60 degree. 60 (degree) + 30 (degree) = 90 (degree) --> A right angle. We also have 30 degree = π/6 (at this point, you should know that "rad" can be conveniently omitted)

Therefore, $cos(π/3)=sin(π/6)$. The side opposite to the 30 degree angle in a triangle is half as long as the hypotenuse, or $sin(π/6)= 1/2$.

Then, we have $cos(π/3)=1/2$